# htaccess file extension rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

anyone have an example of how to write url file extension

specific rewrite...
http://www.site.com/members.html to http://www.site.com/main

and then remove all extension for all files ending in *.html
http://www.site.com/*.html to http://www.site.com/*

also this needs to work with and without www

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On        
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(ssss\.com)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?ssss\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.ssss\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ssss.com/view/%2.html [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^files/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want www.site.com to redirect to site.com (or vice versa), or do you want the redirects to preserve the hostname?

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb is: *put more specific rules first.*

Assuming you want site.com to redirect to www.site.com:

```
RewriteRule ^members.html$ http://www.site.com/main [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```